# Google Cloud - permissions by resource Label or ID

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

How do create a Role (permission) enable very narrow scope - to a specific resource **by ID or Label.**

All documentation/examples seemingly are All Resources of a Type (Compute, etc) to All in a Project or Organization.

I want to give my Testers on labels "test" etc. Also to a very specific "instance-ID".

Cant find any example.
Thanks

Comment: You can assign a service account to a specific compute instance and a few other resources by clicking on the info panel on the right side of the resource. For example, go to `VM Instances` in the Google Cloud Console, click a checkbox next to an instance name and then click the "SHOW INFO PANEL" button near the top right of the page. AFAIK there is no support for specifying tags as conditions. You can use a resource name as a condition. Example: `resource.name.startsWith` https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview

Comment: @John Hanley is right, you should follow the guidance provided above.

Comment: @John Hanley Thanks, I was sort of familiar with CEL. I was hoping/looking for a better solution. My background is AWS - I can do this lot easily in AWS - very granular permissions. In GCP permissions are Project or Org - completely throws me off. But I can try make this work.

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned by *@John Hanley* above, you can assign a service account to a specific compute instance and a few other resources by clicking on the info panel on the right side of the resource. For example, go to VM Instances in the Google Cloud Console, click a checkbox next to an instance name and then click the "SHOW INFO PANEL" button near the top right of the page. AFAIK there is no support for specifying tags as conditions. You can use a resource name as a condition. Example: `resource.name.startsWith`. More details you can find at the documentation [Overview of IAM Conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview).

As a possible solution, you can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) at the [Google Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to change this behavior.